# Reformulemos el texto que sale cuando fallamos una auditoria

Tags: discusión, traducciones, auditorías-de-revisión

Al fallar una auditoria, aparece un cartel que <strike>dice</strike> decía lo siguiente:

> Esta publicación tiene problemas graves de calidad. Es una mera
>   tontería ofensiva, irrelevante, contenido no deseado, está
>   patentemente fuera del tema o es por lo demás irremediable; los
>   lectores la hallarán ofensiva o desagradable en lugar de útil. Cuando
>   revises tales publicaciones, **elimínalas** o **recomienda su
>   eliminación**.

Sin embargo, a varios nos pareció muy "agresivo" o "mala onda", así que rápidamente lo cambiamos a:

> Esta publicación tiene graves problemas de calidad. La misma no tiene
>   sentido, es irrelevante, contenido no deseado, está fuera de tópico o
>   simplemente no se puede arreglar; los lectores no la hallarán útil.
>   Cuando revises tales publicaciones, **elimínalas** o **recomienda su
>   eliminación**.

Sin embargo, estaría bueno que revisemos entre todos esta traducción, y hagamos las mejoras que creamos pertinentes.

El texto esta en [traducir.win](https://traducir.win/string/5960)

Y el original, que tampoco es muy amistoso que digamos, dice:

> This post has severe quality issues. It is abusive nonsense, noise,
>   spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will
>   find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful. Please **delete**
>   or **recommend deletion** when reviewing such posts.

Comment: Lo único que cambiaría es la parte de "está fuera de tópico" por "es un tema no relacionado",  en el resto del sitio "off-topic" ha sido traducido con alguna variación de esa frase.

Comment: Yo le cambiaría "arreglar" por "corregir" y agregaría "contiene palabras ofensivas o "es contenido ofensivo" sin la parte original de "mera tontería...".

Comment: @DiegoTorres ojo porque ya dice es contenido no deseado, seria como redundante? agregalo como una respuesta porfa...

Comment: @FranIslas lo reformulas como una respuesta?

Answer (score 5):

Yo le cambiaría *"arreglar"* por *"corregir"* y le de agregaría *"contiene palabras ofensivas"* o *"es contenido ofensivo"* sin la parte original de *"mera tontería..."*.
Quedando algo así:

> Esta publicación tiene graves problemas de calidad. La misma no tiene
>   sentido, es irrelevante, es contenido ofensivo, contenido no deseado,
>   es un tema no relacionado o simplemente no se puede corregir; los
>   lectores no la hallarán útil. Cuando revises tales publicaciones,
>   elimínalas o recomienda su eliminación.

Comment: Te animas a editarlo en traducir.win ??